# How to write to log files in java?

Tags: java, log4j

I have made a java application and wants to generate log files so whenever my client would encounter some problem, he can deliver me those log files so that I can correct my code accordingly.

1. Kindly provide me a small sample program that writes a statement to a log file. Kindly mention the .class files you are using with their full import statements.
2. The application is multi-threaded so Is it better to generate separate log files for each thread or not?
3. Is it better to clear all previous log files before starting the program?

Comment: Have a go at writing the code yourself and the come here if you've got a specific problem that you need help with.

Comment: I agree... this question doesn't help anyone, and you can get more examples than you can count on google.

Comment: Is this votable for deletion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

macleojw is correct: You should try writing the code yourself.

Here is an overview of the [Java logging framework](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html) that ships with the JDK.  You may wish to check out [Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) and [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html).

Regarding the second part of your question (which was editted out for some reason) I would recommend having all threads log to the same file but logging the thread name along with the log message allowing you to grep the file for a specific thread if required.  Also, with most logging frameworks you can configure them to maintain a rolling window of the last N log files rather than explicitly deleting old files when an application starts.

Answer (score 3):

Apache [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html) does everything you require. I hope that you can figure out how to use it on your own.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html), and specifically [this set](http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/log4j/log4j.html) of step-by-step examples. It's pretty trivial.